# mutex on different instances of django model

Tags: python, django, docker, object, blockchain

I'm creating a django-docker project where each user has their own docker container running an agent that manages their blockchain wallet. The problem I'm running into is that sometimes the server needs to start a container to manage user connections, and the user starts their docker container on login as well. If the server and the user both logout at the same time, it may try to delete a container twice. likewise if the user and the server start a docker container at the same time, we would have two copies of the same docker container running. I've used a couple semaphores and a lock to solve the problem on paper, but I'm wondering if I create two agent objects using:

```
agent_obj_1 = agent.objects.get(wallet_name=request.session["wallet"])
agent_obj_2 = agent.objects.get(wallet_name=request.session["wallet"]) 
agent_obj_1.start()
agent_obj_2.start()
```

where each agent has a lock and semaphore local variable, and I lock the mutex on agent_obj_1, can I still lock agent_obj_2 because they are different instances? or can I not lock agent_obj_2 because it is only a different referance pointing to the same object in memory as agent_obj_1? ie. **do agent_obj_1 and agent_obj_2 share a lock instance variable defined in the __init__() method?** here is the relevant part of my agent class in models.py for reference

```
class agent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seed = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    wallet_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sem = Semaphore(value=2)
        self.create = Lock()
        super(agent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start(self):
        self.sem.acquire()
        self.create.acquire()
        proc = self.find_or_create()
        self.create.release()
```

edit: To clarify, the agent object has already been saved to the django database using:

```
agent_obj = agent(user, email, ...)
agent_obj.save()
```

I'm asking if django creates a new instance of the model each time I retrieve it or if the instance is saved in the database and django gives me a reference to the instance each time I retrieve it from the database

Comment: So you're asking if the two separate instances are in fact separate instances? Yes, they are.

Comment: I'm asking if django creates two references or two intances when retrieving the same object from the database twice

Comment: They're two instances. But even if they weren't, Django is usually served by multiple processes; there you can definitely count on separate data.

Comment: ah I see, I'll have to make a work-around using a class scope lock instead or something

Comment: I'm looking at redis now and it seems like it'll work for what i need, thanks for the tip